# java bytecode optimization, how to handle exception

Tags: java, optimization, exception, bytecode

Consider the following Java class with no concurrent access.

```
class C{
 int x;
 public void m1(int y){
  this.x = y;
  m2(y);
 }
 public void m2(int y){
  System.out.println("m2"); <- or anything else that does not affect this.x
 }
}
```

+edit
Since m1() has only read-read relation on y, Can jit compiler optimize m1() by changing the order of execution to the following? does it break the java model consistency? 
-edit

```
 public void m1(int y){
  m2(y);
  this.x = y;
 }
```

in case m1() can be optimized, what if m2() throws an exception in the optimized code, is the affectation still be executed?

I didn't understand the javase7 specs, what happens in such scenario?

[oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10)

> A Java Virtual Machine may permit a small but bounded amount of execution to occur before an asynchronous exception is thrown. This delay is permitted to allow optimized code to detect and throw these exceptions at points where it is practical to handle them while obeying the semantics of the Java programming language.
>
> [...]
>   Exceptions thrown by the Java Virtual Machine are precise: when the
>   transfer of control takes place, **all effects of the instructions
>   executed before the point from which the exception is thrown must
>   appear to have taken place**. No instructions that occur after the point
>   from which the exception is thrown may appear to have been evaluated.
>   If optimized code has speculatively executed some of the instructions
>   which follow the point at which the exception occurs, such code must
>   be prepared to hide this speculative execution from the user-visible
>   state of the program

I understood the roll back behavior, but I didn't understand what will happen to the "not executed" instructions. technically the affectation was not "executed" because of the optimization, does this mean that it won't be executed ever?

Comment: What optimization are you talking about? You do realize that you are working with primitives, right?

Comment: @MuratK. I fully understand that, but the jit compiler can always optimize the bytecode: it can change the order of execution of instructions

Comment: The JIT can not *always* reorder bytecode, there are restrictions related to volatile fields, synchronized blocks and the cited exception guarantees. If speculatively executed code would throw an exception, that exception would need to be held pending and only be actually thrown when the execution flow reaches a point where the throwing instruction is no longer speculative. If a control flow change occured before that, the pending exception would need to be rolled back as well.

Comment: @Durandal I agree with you, at least that's the logical way things should be executed, unfortunately nothing is mentioned in oracle's docs, but on the other side it could be the developer's fault as well and jit allows itself to break the code, the developer didn't use the try,catch,finally block or for not passing this.x to m2() instead of y. that way he will force JIT to affect this.x before passing it to m2() since write comes before read so JIT can't flip the order of execution (the last one is documented in the jdk7 specs).

Comment: @user The JIT is not allowed to break code, except within the restrictions described in the memory model. The spec doesn't explicitly list everything the VM can't do because that would be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing together two concepts whose only thing, they have in common, is that you didn’t understood them.

Reordering is an optimization that is in no way allowed to modify the outcome of a code execution. It is therefore obsolete to ask questions like “*is the JVM allowed to reorder this code in a way that it breaks it?*”. Of course not. The only thing that is possible, is that the result may *appear* to materialize in a different order to a different thread, in the absence of proper synchronization.

Besides, you should ask yourself why you think

```
public void m1(int y){
    m2(y);
    this.x = y;
}
```

is an optimization over

```
public void m1(int y){
    this.x = y;
    m2(y);
}
```

What’s the improvement?

The other thing you have picked from the specification are *asynchronous exceptions*, a special thing that only applies to [two scenarios](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10-110-C):

> – The stop method of class Thread or ThreadGroup was invoked, or
>
> – An internal error occurred in the Java Virtual Machine implementation

These are obviously very special conditions and it should be obvious that optimized code should not be required to constantly poll for these conditions. The cited paragraph describes the circumstances under which such an exception could be delayed, but it should be clear that these restrictions do not lift the other existing restrictions, i.e. that optimizations may not alter the result of an execution.

---

In other words, it’s pointless to look at isolated instructions and think, a JVM has nothing better to do than shuffling them around. The general rule of optimizations is that they must not change the observable effect and we can’t tell what is observable in your application from that isolated snippet. E.g. if the variable `x` is never read, it might be that it will never written at all. It might be even the case that the instance of `C` which holds the variable `x` is never created, as it is not needed for producing the side effect of printing that message. It’s all about changes you won’t notice…

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry I couldn't come up with a more meaningful example. I totally understand the general rule of optimization you mentioned, but unfortunately there are couple of exceptions documented, RAV optimization and [John Regehr](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161) I was just wondering if this case can be another exception as well since nothing is documented about the java optimization process.

Comment: You can find a lot of papers regarding optimizations used in specific JVMs, e.g. OpenJDK/Oracle in the internet. However, there is no standard optimization process as each implementation is free to optimize in which way it likes as long as the semantics as specified in the JVM are maintained. The article from John Regehr already explains that Java differs from C/C++ regarding non-termination handling and you can generalize this to “Java has no ‘*undefined behavior*’ at all”. Even in the case of data races, threads will never read “out of thin air” values (besides possible word tearing).